# How do Wireless Security Protocols work?

Tags: networking, wifi, wpa2

For example, my home router use WPA2-AES as wireless security protocol. When I access a webpage, traffic coming from my desktop to home router will be encrypted with WPA2. However, when my router forward traffic to the internet (toward the webserver), is it still encrypted with WPA2? Or those wireless security protocols like WPA2 (or WAP, WEP, etc) only works inside my WLAN?

Hope for best explain with simple terms as I'm not a tech savvy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPA and other wireless security protocols only encrypt the wireless link between your PC and your (wireless access point) router.

If you are using HTTPS to talk to the web server, then the TCP session is also encrypted between your PC and the web server.